# How to differentiate pdf document types with PDFSharp?

Tags: ocr, pdfsharp

There are basically 4 types of pdf files.
• PDF Image Only
• PDF Searchable Image Exact
• PDF Searchable Image Compact
• PDF Formatted Text and Graphics
 I need to know how to differentiate a given pdf document in-order to perform OCR.

I've tried something like this, but the given pdf which identified as Image only (mentioned as Scanned in my code) failed to be converted as an image using Image.fromStream method.

```
 public static PdfType GetPdfType(Stream sourcePdf)
    {
        PdfDocument pdf = PdfReader.Open(sourcePdf);

        PdfDictionary pg = pdf.Pages[0];

        PdfDictionary res = pg.Elements.GetDictionary("/Resources");

        PdfDictionary xobj = res.Elements.GetDictionary("/XObject");

        PdfDictionary font = res.Elements.GetDictionary("/Font");

        if (xobj == null)
        {
            return PdfType.Text;
        }
        else if (xobj != null && font != null)
        {
            return PdfType.ScannedText;
        }
        else
            return PdfType.Scanned;
    }
```

Edit: Here is the code snippet where I try to add images which are extracted from pdf file

```
public static Collection<Image> GetExtractedImagesFromPDF(Stream sourcePdf, string outputPath)
    {
        Collection<Image> extractedImages = new Collection<Image>();

        PdfDocument pdf = PdfReader.Open(sourcePdf);

        for (int pageNumber = 0; pageNumber < pdf.Pages.Count; pageNumber++)
        {
            PdfDictionary pg = pdf.Pages[pageNumber];

            // recursively search pages, forms and groups for images.
            PdfDictionary obj = FindImageInPDFDictionary(pg);

            if (obj != null)
            {
                byte[] bytes = obj.Stream.Value;
                ImageConverter ic = new ImageConverter();
                //Image img = (Image)ic.ConvertFrom(bytes);  // throws parameter not valid error
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                Image img = Image.FromStream(ms, false, true);  // throws parameter not valid error
                extractedImages.Add(img);
            }
        }

        return extractedImages;
    }
```

And this is the FindImageInPdfDictionary method

```
static PdfDictionary FindImageInPDFDictionary(PdfDictionary pg)
    {

        PdfDictionary res = pg.Elements.GetDictionary("/Resources");
        if (res != null)
        {
            PdfDictionary xobj = res.Elements.GetDictionary("/XObject");

            if (xobj != null)
            {
                ICollection<PdfItem> items = xobj.Elements.Values;

                foreach (PdfItem item in items)
                {
                    PdfReference reference = item as PdfReference;
                    if (reference != null)
                    {
                        PdfDictionary xObject = reference.Value as PdfDictionary;

                        if (xObject != null && xObject.Elements.GetString("/Subtype") == "/Image")
                        {
                            return xObject;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Are you referring to Image.FromStream from System.Drawing? PDF files contain "PDF images", not "Windows images" and some conversion has to be done. Where is PdfType coming from?

Comment: I'm referrinf to Image.FromStream from System Drawing. I did the conversions too. It is working with the pdf which contains jpeg image, but throwing Parameter not valid error for other types when I try to convert. 
I'll add the code to the main post for your reference.

Comment: JPEG images are stored in JFIF format (and whole JPEG file is included in the PDF file), but other images use an encoding that is similar to Windows BMP but not quite the same (IIRC new lines start at byte boundaries, not DWORD boundaries) so data has to be converted. PDFsharp includes the code from Windows BMP to PDF format, but not the other way. CCITT encoding is also possible and yet another story.